# I'm creating a function where non Login user cant add to cart

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Using props for ReactJS, Im creating a function where non login user can't Add to Cart. I'm using props, useState and uesEffect but it's not working.

Even if Im logged in I still cant add to cart, seems props is not working. Can you please see whats the problem with my code?

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DATA from '../Data';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { addItem, delItem } from '../redux/actions/index'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';



const Product = (props) => {

    const [cartBtn, setCartBtn] = useState("Add to Cart")
    const [auth, setauth] = useState(false);
    const [auth1, setauth1] = useState(true);
    


    const proid = useParams();
    const proDetail = DATA.filter(x=>x.id == proid.id)
    const product = proDetail[0];
    console.log(product);


    const isLoggedin = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch('/auth', {
          method : "GET",
          headers : {
            Accept : "application/json",
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
          },
        credentials : "include"
        });
             if(res.status === 200) {
               setauth(true)
               setauth1(false)
            }

            if(res.status === 401) {
              setauth(false)
              setauth1(true)
             }

          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)

          }
        }

        useEffect(() => {
          isLoggedin();
        }, []);
    

    return (
        <>

                {props.auth ? 
                    <>
                    <button onClick={()=>handleCart(product)} className="btn btn-primary my-3">{cartBtn}</button>
                    <NavLink to="/cart" className="btn btn-outline-primary ">Go to Cart</NavLink>
                    
                    </> 
                    :
                    <>
                    <NavLink to="/" className="btn btn-outline-primary mt-5 fw-bold">Login to Buy</NavLink>
                    </>
                }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
        );
}


export default Product;
```

[![Here is design of my app ][It's not showing 'Add to Cart' and 'Go to Cart' button]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bomUj.png)

Comment: please ignore this code 
const proid = useParams();
 const proDetail = DATA.filter(x=>x.id == proid.id)
 const product = proDetail[0];
 console.log(product);   /// thats not part of it ...

Answer (score 0):

just type for non login user,

```
        {!isLoggedin ? 
            <>
            <button onClick={()=>handleCart(product)} className="btn btn-primary my-3">{cartBtn}</button>
            <NavLink to="/cart" className="btn btn-outline-primary ">Go to Cart</NavLink>
            
            </> 
            :
            <>
            <NavLink to="/" className="btn btn-outline-primary mt-5 fw-bold">Login to Buy</NavLink>
            </>
        }
```